# assigning values to input array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

if I have this:

```js
function add(){
  var val = document.getElementById("item").value;
  
  document.getElementById("items").value = val;
  
}
```

```html
<table>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="items[]" id="items[]" value="" >
    
    <button onclick="add()" type="button"> Add</button>
    
</table>
```

so I just want add some values to input items[], It's possible? in javascript I use push(), but in this case I don't know what to do.

Comment: The input's value will be a string, so you could potentially use a `+=` and include a comma with your appended value. 
However, personally, I would probably split `items`' existing value into an array, push the new value into that array, then join the array back into a string before assigning it to the value again.

Comment: The ID is `item[]`, not `items`.

Comment: I updated code, but I have this "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')

Comment: `items` is not the same as `items[]`.

Comment: I do not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new `items[]` element for each value that you're adding. Then the middleware on the server should automatically create an array with all these values.

```js
function add(){
  var val = document.getElementById("item").value;
  
  var item = document.createElement("input");
  item.type = "hidden";
  item.name = "items[]";
  item.value = val;  
  document.getElementById("form").appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="">
    
    <button onclick="add()" type="button"> Add</button>
    
</form>
```

Comment: if I send it to control the input items[], it will arrive??

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: it's work, but only one value, If I added 10 item in array items only saved last  item.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the controller script. In PHP it needs to loop over the array `$_POST['items']`, there should be something similar in other languages.